# Tensorflow on windows 7 - failed to load the native tensoflow runtime

Tags: python, windows

I'm using Python 3.5 on Windows 7. I have installed tensorflow and tensorflow-gpu version 1.1 through pip but when I try to run this command

```
import tensorflow as tf
```

I'm getting this error[part 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OKoUR.jpg)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Toshiba\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module(mname)
```

ImportError: No module named _pywrap_tensorflow_internal

```
Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.
```

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_problems

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.

Comment: Please show the complete traceback as text in your question and properly formatted as code instead of parts as image and parts as text with markdown formatting applied where this makes no sense.  Does your system fulfill the requirements to run TensorFlow with GPU support given in the TensorFlow documentation?

Answer (score 0):

You may well be missing the CUDAnn DLLs - I had the same issue and installing these fixed it on Win 7.

These are a prerequisite as per https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows

Get the CUDA dlls from here:
https://developer.nvidia.com/rdp/cudnn-download

You specifically need the v6.0 library (and in your case windows 7).

Once unzipped, copy the files in the zip to the equivalent folders (bin/lib/include) of your main NVidia CUDA installation. For me this was D:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v8.0\